# Laravel 5.4 errors in web browser not showing instead 404 error shows

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, laravel-5.3

I've really fed up with this problem, for the past 4 hours i worked on it ,but didn't get proper solution.

**Server**

php-fpm-nginx (Laravel 5.4).

Problem:Error messages are not shown in web browser

**Solutions i've tried**

1.Enabled error reporting in php.ini (its works fine testted with a sample php file).

2.`777` permissions for `storage` and `bootstrap` folder.

3. set `APP_DEBUG=true` in `.env`

I can able to see error messages in `storage/logs` folder but it didn't displayed in browser

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/errors << have you set up the APP_DEBUG to true in your config/app.php file?

Comment: yes ,Its setuped in `.env` file

Comment: Double check the actual file, my project has it in the env too, but the app.php is not set up to read the .env, so mine is false.

Comment: @RickCalder is right, make (APP_DEBUG, true) at both the places 
inside "config/app.php"  'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', true), and in ".env" APP_DEBUG=true.  Hope it will help.

Comment: Which errors? What do you see instead of errors?

Comment: shows  404 error page thats default nginx error page

Comment: Perhaps the default error view is not found?

Comment: @apokryfos instead of showing error message it shows default nginx 404 error page

Comment: The error message shown in localhost but not in the live server

Comment: @RickCalder directly added `debug`=true in `config.php`file it works  fine in localhost but returns 404error page in live server (when a php error occu)red

Comment: This was also tried

Comment: _`I can able to see error messages in storage/logs folder`_ and whats that error  you read over there.

Comment: @NarendrasingmalhSisodia  normal error messages (ie syntax errors,query exceptions)

Comment: try php artisan config:clear command and php artisan config:cache.

Answer (score 0):

In your nginx config, Are you sure that root is point to you public folder?
Something like this:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    ....
    root       /path/laravel/public;
    ......
}
```

Comment: This should be posted as a comment. Please see [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/163589/338114) to understand when to post an answer and when to post a comment. There should be no guessing in an answer.